# Classes And Objects

Tags: c#, class, object, console-application

Can a class have 2 `objects` with the same name? If yes then while displaying, which particular object's roll, name and course details get printed?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Student st=null;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Records");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            st = new Student();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter roll");
            st.roll = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter name");
            st.name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter course");
            st.course = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Show Records");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Roll "+st.roll.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Name "+st.name);
            Console.WriteLine("Course "+st.course);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class Student
{
    public int roll;
    public string name;
    public string course;
}
```

Comment: So, each `Student` needs multiple courses, or something different?

Comment: You only have one Student object in st, that keeps getting overwritten.  You need to use a collection or array of Student.

Comment: @Grant Winney, it is working just fine, I m getting the right input and output but i m not confident about my understanding of the concept of objects for I have asked the query above.

Comment: @Grant Winney, try it for yourself.

Comment: @OldProgrammer How is it that I am still getting the right input and output when the object should practically be overwritten??

Comment: @OldProgrammer That is my question dear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can create a `List<Students>` which is basically a list of `Students`

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Student> sts = new List<Student>();
        Student st = null;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Records");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            st = new Student();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter roll");
            st.roll = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter name");
            st.name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter course");
            st.course = Console.ReadLine();
            sts.Add(st);  // this is the line to be added to populate the list
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Show Records");
        for (int i = 0; i < sts.Count; i++)
        {
            st = sts[i];  // this needs to be added to read from list
            Console.WriteLine("Roll "+st.roll.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Name "+st.name);
            Console.WriteLine("Course "+st.course);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class Student 
{
   public int roll;
   public string name;
   public string course;
}
```

Comment: My question is, how can i make multiple objects of class student with the same name, st=new student();

Comment: If you do that, you are overriding the object

Comment: Which is what I am asking, you are making an object in a loop construct, therefore, each time the loop goes to work an object with the same name gets made. st=new student();

Comment: @androidrill: no, a variable gets assigned a new value.  That's not the same thing as an object with the same name.

Comment: @jmoreno How is it possible? "new" keyword means a new object is being formed within the loop construct, everytime loop goes to work.

Comment: @androidrill think of it like this: you are a object and you are given a new job. So, now you have the current job and the last job is gone

Comment: @androidrill: you are using a non-standard term, which makes answers to your question a bit difficult.  Yes, the new means a new object is being created.  A reference to that object is stored in the variable st, variables can only hold a single value. A variable is absolutely, fundamentally, incapable of holding multiple values. That single value CAN be a reference to an object that has more than one value in it. So, the interpretation of the stored value can lead to "multiple" values, but only one value can be stored at a time. This answer shows how to store and get access to multiple values.

Comment: @jmoreno, I think you should delete this `A variable is absolutely, fundamentally, incapable of holding multiple values` since a List<> is also a variable and what about arrays??

Comment: @AmitJoki: the value that a list or array variable contains is a reference to an object.  That object can contain more than one value. But you can't have a variable that has as its value two different lists or a list and an array. Even an integer variable that is used for a bit mask, can contain only a single integer, even though you might give meaning to each individual bit.  As I said, that value can be a reference to an object with more than one value, but the variable itself has a single value.

Comment: @jmoreno ok now I know.

Comment: @AmitJoki: your answer is correct, but does not explain why you have to create a list instead of having a variable with multiple values.  I was trying to help clarify why the answer "No, but you can creat a List" is correct, but if you feel my comments are misleading, distracting or incorrect, I am willing to delete them.

Comment: NO, your comments are helpful. Can I incorporate them in my answer?

Comment: @androidrill, yes. I did it. But delete these comments asking for upvote.